# How to display an image in polar coordinates with Python?

Tags: python, image, polar-coordinates

I'm looking for a way to transform an image in polar coordinates using Python. The result I expect is the same as the following image (done in Matlab): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKBBd.png

I already tried using *cv2.linearPolar* but I couldn't achieve this result.

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
h, w, _ = image.shape
image2 = cv2.linearPolar(image, (w / 2, h / 2), min(w, h) / 2,
                         cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP + cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
```

Comment: Quick and easy! I didn't know it was possible to add flags. Thanks so much!